# Cannot Open Source File

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, com

I am attempting to open MSO.dll for a project written in C++ involving Excel automation. However, when I attempt to #import the MSO.dll, I get a "cannot open source file" error. I have added the file path to both the additional include directories (in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General) and the linker additional include directories.

Here is my code so far:

```
#pragma region Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
//#include "Solution1.h"
#pragma endregion


#pragma region Import the type libraries

#import "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE12\\MSO.DLL" \
    rename("RGB", "MSORGB") \
    rename("DocumentProperties", "MSODocumentProperties")

using namespace Office;
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, but post the text.

Comment: Was not aware, edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the path correct? This path should vary based upon Windows bitness and Office version. Specifically, on my Win64 machine with Office 2016, this file exists at

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE16\\MSO.DLL"
```

Here's a quick way to search for this file on your `C:` drive. Just open a command line and run the following. Copy and paste the path (you don't even really need to escape the backslashes, since paths in `#include` and `#import` directives are not treated as C++ string literals).

```
attrib /s c:\mso.dll
```